# Coverting certain elements in a nested array to a hash

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write some code to convert elements of this nested array:

```
array = [
  [['number'], ['name'], ['postion'], ['points']],
  [['91'], ['dave'], ['center'], ['42']],
  [['82'], ['sanjay'], ['behind'], ['14']],
  [['133'], ['ayman'], ['front'], ['23']]
]
```

to a hash like:

```
user1 = {number: 91, name: dave, postion: center, points: 42}
user2 = {number: 82, name: Sanjay, ...}
```

If anyone has an easy way to understand the code, it would be thankful.

Comment: Are they always just number, name, center and points?

Comment: They are  - number, name, position, points.

Comment: Where does that array come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes more sense to use an array `users` (rather than variables `user1`, `user2` and so on) so the code will work with any number of users. The value for user `i` is then `user[i]` (counting from user `0`).

```
keys, *values = array.map(&:flatten)
users = [keys.map(&:to_sym)].product(values).map { |pair| pair.transpose.to_h }
  #=> [{:number=>"91", :name=>"dave", :postion=>"center", :points=>"42"},
  #    {:number=>"82", :name=>"sanjay", :postion=>"behind", :points=>"14"},
  #    {:number=>"133", :name=>"ayman", :postion=>"front", :points=>"23"}]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
keys, *values = array.map(&:flatten)
  #=> [["number", "name", "postion", "points"],
  #    ["91", "dave", "center", "42"],
  #    ["82", "sanjay", "behind", "14"],
  #    ["133", "ayman", "front", "23"]]
keys
  #=> ["number", "name", "postion", "points"]
values
  #=> [["91", "dave", "center", "42"],
  #    ["82", "sanjay", "behind", "14"],
  #    ["133", "ayman", "front", "23"]]
a = keys.map(&:to_sym)
  #=> [:number, :name, :postion, :points]
b = [a]
  #=> [[:number, :name, :postion, :points]]
c = b.product(values)
  #=> [[[:number, :name, :postion, :points], ["91", "dave", "center", "42"]],
       [[:number, :name, :postion, :points], ["82", "sanjay", "behind", "14"]],
     [[:number, :name, :postion, :points], ["133", "ayman", "front", "23"]]]
c.map { |pair| pair.transpose.to_h }
  # <return value above>
```

When performing the last step each element of `c` is passed to the block, the block variable `pair` is assigned to that value and the block calculation is performed. When the first element of `c` is passed to the block the following steps are executed.

```
pair = c.first
  #=> [[:number, :name, :postion, :points], ["91", "dave", "center", "42"]]
d = pair.transpose
  #=> [[:number, "91"], [:name, "dave"], [:postion, "center"], [:points, "42"]]
d.to_h
  #=> {:number=>"91", :name=>"dave", :postion=>"center", :points=>"42"}
```

The remaining calculations are similar.

Comment: good idea to use `product`. The last link in your chain can be `.map { |a| a.transpose.to_h }` if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @sagarpandya82. I'll make the change.

Answer (score 3):

```
header, *data = array.map(&:flatten)
user1, user2, user3 = data.map { |row| header.zip(row).to_h }
```

Comment: Note that the keys in the computed hashes are to be symbols. You might insert the statement `header.map!(&:to_sym)`

Answer (score 2):

To get your data to the example output with an arbitrary number of fields and users, you might do something like this:

```
array =  [
[['number'], ['name'], ['postion'], ['points']],
[  ['91'],  ['dave'], ['center'],  ['42']],
[  ['82'],   ['sanjay'],  ['behind'],    ['14']],
[  ['133'], ['ayman'], ['front'],    ['23']]]

temp, data={},{}
array.transpose.map { |(h, *rest)| temp[h]=rest.flatten }

(1..temp.max_by { |k,v| v.length }[1].length)
             .each_with_index { |n, i| data["user%d" % [n]]=temp.map { |k,l| [k[0], l[i]] } }
data.map { |k, v| data[k]=v.to_h }
```

Then you get:

```
> data 
{"user1"=>{"number"=>"91", "name"=>"dave", "postion"=>"center", "points"=>"42"}, "user2"=>{"number"=>"82", "name"=>"sanjay", "postion"=>"behind", "points"=>"14"}, "user3"=>{"number"=>"133", "name"=>"ayman", "postion"=>"front", "points"=>"23"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get each keys for the next hashes taking the first array in the main array like:

```
array.first.flatten
# => ["number", "name", "postion", "points"]
```

So, then you can get the rest of array, that's starting from the index 1 up to the last element, "flatten" it and get an array each 4 values, like:

```
p array[1..-1].flatten.each_slice(4).to_a
[["91", "dave", "center", "42"], ["82", "sanjay", "behind", "14"], ["133", "ayman", "front", "23"]]
```

So then you can create a hash with each array with 4 values inside each of them and using each value in the keys array like the hash key:

```
p array[1..-1].flatten.each_slice(4).map.with_index{|e,i|
  Hash[e.map.with_index{|f,i| [keys[i], f]}]
}
# [
#   {"number"=>"91",  "name"=>"dave",   "postion"=>"center", "points"=>"42"}, 
#   {"number"=>"82",  "name"=>"sanjay", "postion"=>"behind", "points"=>"14"}, 
#   {"number"=>"133", "name"=>"ayman",  "postion"=>"front",  "points"=>"23"}
# ]
```

Having that you could iterate over it, or create your local or instance variables as you need.